# Store multiple objects in json column

Tags: laravel, api

I have table  with some json column. I want to store multi  objects in the json column in Laravel.

My json column look like this `"position":[{"lat" : 500, "lon" : 5000, "date":"2020:04:21 16:58:23"}]`.

**this is a function in a service that , i call in my controller**

```
 public static function savePositionCamion($id_tournee, $position)
    {
        $geoTour = GeoTournee::where('geo_tournee.id_tournee', $id_tournee)->first(['position']);

        if (!$geoTour) {
            $geoTournee = new self();
            $geoTournee->id_tournee = $id_tournee;
            $geoTournee->position = $position;
            return $geoTournee->save() ? $geoTournee : false;
        } else {
            $arr_pos = json_decode($geoTour->position);
            dd($arr_pos);

        }


    }
```

**in the controller i call the function like this**

```
$geoTourne = GeoTournee::savePositionCamion($request->id_tournee, json_encode($request->position));
```

anyone can help me to achieve this ! thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON. You have JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model:

```php
class GeoTournee extends Model
{
    ...
    protected $casts = [
        'position' => 'array',
    ];
    ...
}
```

So you can save this json field like this:

```php
$geoTournee->position = $position;
$geoTournee->save();
```

Accessing the `position` attribute and it will automatically be deserialized from `JSON` into a PHP `array`. When you set the value of the `position` attribute, the given `array` will automatically be serialized back into `JSON` for storage:

And you don't need to create `savePositionCamion` function, you can use `firstOrCreate` instead:

```php
GeoTournee::firstOrCreate(['id_tournee' => $id_tournee], [ 'position' => $position ]);
```

Comment: Ok thank you @TsaiKoga , i test it and tell you the result. I have a question how  to  validate  position fields ?

Comment: @Moum If it is from `$request` and an array, you can use validator to validate each element of array:`$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    "position"    => "required|array",
    "position.*.lat"  => "required",...
]);`

Comment: Hi @TsaiKoga i test  what you said it's work , but in   the position column i want to save multiple object  after each add of  a new position for the same id_tournee.

Comment: @Moum do u mean that append an object to the original position array?

Comment: yes that it @TsaiKoga  the json column can contains multi objects like this "position":[{"lat" : 8000, "lon" : 5000, "date":"2020:04:21 16:58:23"},{"lat" : 8000, "lon" : 5000, "date":"2020:04:21 16:58:23"},{"lat" : 8000, "lon" : 5000, "date":"2020:04:21 16:58:23"}]

Comment: @Moum if the `$position = [["lat" => 8000, "lon" => 5000, "date"=>"2020:04:21 16:58:23"],["lat" =>8000, "lon" => 5000, "date"=>"2020:04:21 16:58:23"],["lat" =>8000, "lon" => 5000, "date"=>"2020:04:21 16:58:23"]]`, you can just save it, the json column will store this objects.

Comment: yes @TsaiKoga except that I have to add a new object to the array each time. this is the final structure after several additions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212363/discussion-between-tsaikoga-and-moum).

Comment: firstOrCreate does not successfully find first for json columns